# How to use one icon from different image files?

Tags: jquery, html, css

[Here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png) is the set of icons within one image file. And [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png) is another set.

How can I create a link (`a href`) with usage of icon from one file, on hover it should take icon from another file (the same position) and on click - from third file?

Here is the CSS just to use one icon:

```
width: 16px;  
height: 16px;  
background-image: 
url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); 
background-position: -32px -128px;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is define styles for the different states of the link(s):

```
a:link,a:visited { /* for regular non-hovered, non-active link styles */
    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;
    background-image:
    url(images/defaultStateImage.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}

a:hover { /* for hover/mouse-over styles */
    url(images/hoverStateImage.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}

a:active { /* for click/mouse-down state styles */
    url(images/clickStateImage.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}
```

Comment: If you update to a newer jQuery UI and they changed their icon image stuff, I'm guessing you would have to adjust the background-positions here as well, right?

Answer (score 3):

Use a selector, and change the a:active to the right image (you only linked to two)

```
a:link, a:visited {
    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;  
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px; 
}
a:hover {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png); 
}
a:active {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to **define the background-image** for each icon-set (in this case three), and **define the background-position** for each icon that you are going to be using. (assuming the position of the icon is the same for the icon templates)

Also, I do not recommend you use the general link selector `a`, but **assign a class for the icon buttons**, as you might have other icon sets/links:

```
a.icon:link,
a.icon:visited

a.icon:hover

a.icon:active
```

Here is a sample of the general definition of the `.icon` class, and a button:

```
a.icon:link, a.icon:visited {
    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;  
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}
a.icon:hover { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png); }
a.icon:active { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png); }

.button1 { background-position: 0px 0px }
.button2 { background-position: 16px 0px }
.button3 { background-position: 32px 0px }
/// etc.. for each button
```

To use an icon:

```
<a class="icon button1"></a>
```

Comment: The `click` pseudo-class doesn't exists, it's `active`.

Answer (score 1):

Just create another selector. In example:

```
a
{
    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;  
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}

a:hover
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}
```

And about the click event I am not 100% sure but I think that is the one

```
a:active
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_CLICK_IMAGE_HERE_256x240.png); 
    background-position: -32px -128px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your sprite images you do this with a single sprite image.

like this:

```
a{    
    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;  
    background-image: url(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
    background-position: -32px -128px; 
    display:block;
}

a:hover{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/vERDH/3/

check this also [How to make a single image, treated as three different images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440226/how-to-make-a-single-image-treated-as-three-different-images/7440251#7440251)

Answer (score 1):

Your best way is to treat it as any other semantic element, and then just style it as a button.

HTML:

```
<a class="icon icon-travel" href="/travel">Travel Offers</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.icon {
    background: none 0 0 no-repeat;
    width: 16px;  
    height: 16px;  
    text-indent: -10000px;
    display: inline-block; }
a.icon-travel {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
    background-position: -32px -128px; }
a.icon-travel:hover { background-image: url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png); }
```