# how are the facebook images used in css from a single image

Tags: html, css, facebook

after logging in to facebook, if you `right-click` on the image meant to show friend requests just beside the facebook logo at the top left side of the page, and inspect the result in google chrome, you find the css rules as `#fbRequestsJewel.hasNew a.jewelButton`. [This](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yt/r/44p6wOsF0G7.png) is the background image url there.
Number of images inside it and i think those individual images are used in different places in FB,
How is that done? Is it image mapping or what? Why to do in that way instead of using separate images? What are the advantages?

Answer (score 3):

It's called a CSS sprite and is basically an element that uses `background-image` and `background-position` to reuse a single image to show many different smaller images.

It's done to speed up the time taken for a page load load, as each resource the browser requests adds an overhead of an additional HTTP request.

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) has a great article on the usage of CSS sprites.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `Sprite` may be you have to check this answer

### [How to make a single image, treated as three different images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440226/how-to-make-a-single-image-treated-as-three-different-images/7440251#7440251)

check this article for more http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Comment: needs more explaination buddy... you have just given the reference of the article but not answered the question, if you are just giving some link you should place a comment.. by the way upvote to place it quickly..

Comment: @Murtaza; read the article they give the explanation in detail & in a better way :)

Answer (score 0):

hi this is called  css sprite on images 
 Basically when we have individual images on server we have to load each images seperatly.

this will load the image in one single server trip and using css background-position we can displayed the image which we want where ever we need.

You can refer this website for simple and complete understanding of css sprites.
[CSS SPRITES](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)